# GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Cannot parse the unexpected character "."

Tags: graphql, jestjs, apollo-client

I am currently using Apollo-server as my GraphQL server of choice and anytime I try to run tests I get the error indicated in the title. However, my server implementation works as expected.

```js
import 'cross-fetch/polyfill';
import ApolloClient, { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/',
});

const USER = {
  invalidPassWord : {
    name: 'Gbolahan Olagunju',
    password: 'dafe',
    email: 'gbols@example.com'
  },
  validCredentials: {
    name: 'Gbolahan Olagunju',
    password: 'dafeMania',
    email: 'gbols@example.com'
  },
  usedEmail: {
    name: 'Gbolahan Olagunju',
    password: 'dafeMania',
    email: 'gbols@example.com'
  }
};

describe('Tests the createUser Mutation', () => {
  test('should not signup a user with a password less than 8 characters', () => {
    const createUser = gql`
    mutation {
      createUser(data: USER.invalidPassWord){
        token
        user {
          name
          password
          email
          id
        }
      }
    }
    `
    
    client.mutate({
      mutation: createUser
    }).then(res => console.log(res));
  })
})
```

Comment: Is there any error message?

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with the document used in your test. `USER.invalidPassWord` is not valid GraphQL syntax. Presumably you meant to use a template literal there to reference the `USER` variable defined earlier.

Comment: Thanks this seems to be the issue an invalid GraphQL syntax

Answer (score 0):

Doing the GrapQL tutorial at

https://www.howtographql.com/react-apollo/1-getting-started/

gives the same error.

I have razed the "same" issue at their site, though is the problem another in my case.

https://github.com/howtographql/howtographql/issues/1047